# Where can I find temp difference for fluid smoke simulation?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm following an old tutorial online on how to create liquid splashed using the smoke sim. But I can't find the Temp Diff setting in my version or it's equivalent. Could anyone help?

I essentially need the smoke not travel upwards and to stay around the emitter which, in the video, is done by reducing the temp difference to 0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this setting does still exist. I’ve used it recently for just this purpose. I don’t remember exactly where though.

Comment: There we are! “Initial temperature” https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/flow.html#settings …and the domain reference balance, “buoyancy density” and “buoyancy heat” https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html

Comment: Like @TheLabCat pointed out, the settings are now somewhere else - because actually Mantaflow is not simply an updated version of the Blender fluid simulation you saw in the old tutorial, it's a completely different system. Some settings are similar, but some are very different. For your task to make the smoke stay around the object, it's not enough to set the _Initial Temperature_ in the _Flow_ object to 0 (like in your example), but the _Buoyancy Density_ in the domain as well, and the other way round - only setting it to 0 in the domain while leaving the flow at 1 let's the smoke rise, too.

Comment: besides your problem...i would recommend watching tutorials with "your" blender version because especially on fluid/smoke simulations the result will be quite different from the older versions without mantaflow...and there are lots of tutorials on yt.